# Who is the one person's name achieved cheating death...?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In the *Star Wars* movie *Revenge of the Sith* we can see he below dialog between Anakin and Sidious (PALPATINE)  after Anakin killed all Jedis:

> **ANAKIN:** What have I done?
>
> **PALPATINE:** You are fulfilling your destiny, Anakin. Become my apprentice. Learn to use the dark side of the Force.
>
> **ANAKIN:** I will do whatever you ask.
>
> **PALPATINE:** Good.
>
> **ANAKIN:** Just help me save Padme's life. I can't live without her. I won't let her die. I want the power to stop death.
>
> **PALPATINE:** To cheat death is a power only one has achieved, but if we work together, I know we can discover the secret.

So my question is, is **PALPATINE** saying the one person's name who achieved cheating death?

Comment: Why on Earth was this downvoted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Darth Plagueis The Wise**

There is a scene earlier in the movie about this:

> **Palpatine**: Did you ever hear the tragedy of Darth Plagueis The Wise?
>
> **Anakin**: No?
>
> **Palpatine**: I thought not. It’s not a story the Jedi would tell you. It’s a Sith legend. Darth Plagueis was a Dark Lord of the Sith, so powerful and so wise he could use the Force to influence the midichlorians to create life… He had such a knowledge of the dark side, he could even keep the ones he cared about from dying.